# savelowerto option from tcolorbox fails inside a wrapper command

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I am experimenting a little bit with a favorite package of mine: `tcolorbox`, the following code is cut out/reduced from a larger 'project', cut down to a command

```
\newcommand{\splitmycontent}[2]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[lowerbox=ignored,savelowerto={lowerboxcontent}]
  #1%
  \tcblower%
  #2%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%
```

The content is actually split outside of the `splitmycontent` into two parts, but let's assume this is done (it works), but the saving the lower part with this approach fails.

Using the direct approach, without 'wrapper', the code works.

I suspect something goes wrong with the verbatim content, but I have no clue at the moment with this message

```
! Bad space factor (0). <recently
read> \@savsf
```

I have the latest updates of TeXLive 2014, so it's most probably no outdated package issue.

Here is a very small MWE, the offending line commented out:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}%

\newcommand{\splitmybox}[2]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[lowerbox=ignored,savelowerto={lowerboxcontent}]
  #1%
  \tcblower%
  #2%
\end{tcolorbox}%
}%


\begin{document}
% Fails
%\splitmybox{Gandalf the Grey}{rides to Saruman the White}%

% Direct usage
\begin{tcolorbox}[lowerbox=ignored,savelowerto={lowerboxcontent}]%
Gandalf the Grey%
\tcblower%
rides to Saruman the White%
\end{tcolorbox}%

% Loading the lower box content
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red]
\input{lowerboxcontent}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You clearly see that `tcolorbox` enters a `verbatim` mode and is not able to find the end of it until it finds the subsequent `\end{tcolorbox}`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I see that, but why does it work outside of a macro?

Comment: Because a macro tokenizes the replacement text, in particular `\end{tcolorbox}` cannot be seen as a string any more.

Comment: @egreg: Well, I learned something again ... Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\tcblower` command makes TeX enter a `verbatim` mode, so the delimiter must be the *string* `\end{tcolorbox}` rather than the tokens `\end{tcolorbox}`.

Solution: use `\scantokens`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}%

\newcommand\splitmybox[2]{%
  \scantokens{\begin{tcolorbox}[lowerbox=ignored,savelowerto={lowerboxcontent}]
    #1%
    \tcblower
    #2%
  \end{tcolorbox}}%
}

\begin{document}

\splitmybox{Gandalf the Grey}{rides to Saruman the White}%

% Loading the lower box content
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red]
\input{lowerboxcontent}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]