# A new environment for the lower part of a tcolorbox

Tags: macros, environments, tcolorbox

I would like to use an environment for the lower part of a tcolorbox instead of just `tcblower` command. I've tried with following code but it fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{lowerpart}{\tcblower}{}

\begin{document}

% This works
\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper part
\tcblower
Lower part
\end{tcolorbox}

% This fails
\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper part
\begin{lowerpart}
Lower part
\end{lowerpart}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The error shown is

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endminipage ...pagefalse \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \expandafter \@iiiparbox \...
l.16 \begin{lowerpart}
```

This problem is probably realted with  [savelowerto option from tcolorbox fails inside a wrapper command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219893/savelowerto-option-from-tcolorbox-fails-inside-a-wrapper-command/219921#219921). But as the question is not the same I don't know if same solution applies here neither how to apply to my code.

Comment: The problem is different; your `\begin{lowerpart}` starts a group and then `\tcblower` issues `\end{tcb@savebox}` at a different group level than expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As egreg already commented, the core of the problem is the group level. `\tcblower` closes a group/environment (simplyfied: the `minipage` for the upper part) and opens another one (simplyfied: the `minipage` for the lower part).

Thanks to the `etoolbox` package which is automatically loaded by `tcolorbox`, you can put `\tcblower` at a very early point before the environment `lowerpart` really starts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{lowerpart}{}{}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lowerpart}{\tcblower}

\begin{document}

% This works
\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper part
\tcblower
Lower part
\end{tcolorbox}

% This works too
\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper part
\begin{lowerpart}
Lower part
\end{lowerpart}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, I would'nt lay may hand into the fire that this new environment `lowerpart` works in combination with trickier things like `savelowerto` etc.

Instead of using a *real* lower part, maybe, just drawing a line with `\tcbline` could be an alternative. This can be used without tricks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{lowerpart}{\tcbline}{}

\begin{document}

% This works
\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper part
\tcblower
Lower part
\end{tcolorbox}

% This works too
\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper part
\begin{lowerpart}
Lower part
\end{lowerpart}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! First solution is good enough. With it is easier to use an environment which hides the use of `tcolorbox`.