# How can I use a minted listing inside a tcolorbox's top half *and* bottom half?

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, grouping

I'm creating reference documentation for a intro-to-programming class.  As part of this, I'm going to have syntax definitions and examples of the syntax.

To write this, I'd like to have LaTeX syntax like the following:

```
\begin{myenv}
% syntax-highlighted syntax definitions
<stuff> <here> <type> <name>(<args>) { <body> }
\tcblower % or better yet, some marker \StartExamples.
          % Escaping with @...@ would obviously be ok here.
% syntax-highlighted examples of syntax being defined.
public static void Main(string[] args) { ... }
\end{myenv}
```

which would give me a lovely two-part tcolorbox with the dotted line across the box separating the abstract definition from the concrete example.  Syntax is of course secondary to a solution…

Sadly, if I actually use `\tcblower` in the above (escaped inside `@@`), I get a *ton* of errors:

```
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   LaTeX Error: \begin{Verbatim} on input line 1 ended by \end{tcb@savebox}.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Missing } inserted.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
_minted-mwe/5C20B662D879F...    5 Error   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
mwe.tex                        32 Error   File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
mwe.tex                        32 Error   FancyVerb Error:
```

The generated file in `_minted-mwe/5C...`:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}]
\PYG{esc}{\csparam{access modifiers}} \PYG{esc}{\csparam{type}} \PYG{esc}{\csparam{name}}\PYG{p}{(}\PYG{esc}{\csparam{parameter definitions\dots}}\PYG{p}{)} \PYG{p}{\PYGZob{}}
  \PYG{esc}{\csparam{method body}}
\PYG{p}{\PYGZcb{}}
\PYG{esc}{\tcblower}
\PYG{k}{public} \PYG{k}{void} \PYG{n+nf}{SayHello}\PYG{p}{(}\PYG{k+kt}{string} \PYG{n}{name}\PYG{p}{)} \PYG{p}{\PYGZob{}}
  \PYG{n}{Console}\PYG{p}{.}\PYG{n}{WriteLine}\PYG{p}{(}\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZdq{}Hello, \PYGZdq{}} \PYG{p}{+} \PYG{n}{name}\PYG{p}{)}\PYG{p}{;}
\PYG{p}{\PYGZcb{}}
\end{Verbatim}
```

I suspect the problem here is the group level as well ([reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269211/17423)) given that `\tcblower` ends up inside `\PYG{esc}{\tcblower}`.  I used to know where `\PYG` ended up, but suffice to say I'd believe it if someone said it wasn't 'naked' after expansion as tcolorbox is probably expecting.

If I *don't* escape the call to `\tcolorbox`, it's interpreted as C# code and gets an angry red box indicating the syntax error.  So, escaping it is most likely necessary.

#### MWE

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}

\tcbuselibrary{minted,xparse}

\NewTCBListing{cssyntax}{O{}m}{
  minted language={csharp},
  adjusted title={Syntax Reference: #2},
  float,
  #1
}

\setminted{
  escapeinside=@@,
}

% the real one is more sophisticated, but for MWE's sake
\newcommand\csparam[1]{$\langle\textit{#1}\rangle$}

\begin{document}
\begin{cssyntax}{Method Use}
@\csparam{access modifiers}@ @\csparam{type}@ @\csparam{name}@(@\csparam{parameter definitions\dots}@) {
  @\csparam{method body}@
}
@\tcblower@ % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
public void SayHello(string name) {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
}
\end{cssyntax}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even if I remove `@\tcblower@ % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -` I get a box with some lower part. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat yeah tcb tries to interpret the csharp code as TeX and typesets it there. To get rid of it you can add `listing only` to the tcb environment options. I figured we would *want* some lower part in the solution, but the lower part that you're seeing is not at all what's desired (I don't think).

Comment: @SchrodingersCat both pieces need to typeset source code.

Comment: OK, but could you indicate what the target output is?

Comment: And the solution proposed in linked question (drawing just a line inside tcbox) is not acceptable for you? I am working on very simillar document, and I (as newbie and as lstlistings user) ended up defining standard listing environment and another tcolorbox environment, that only wraps any ammount of listings environment as needed. I works without problem, but more typing is required.

Comment: I think what you want is not possible, tcblistings try to convert the upper or lower part into TeX result except when `listing only` option is used, but in this case a lower part is not present. I suggest to think into a tcbraster with two boxes where each one can be a listing box.

Comment: @Ignasi That was my assumption as well, though I couldn't quite reason why. This kind of `minted` use doesn't have the same fundamentally fragile nature as I would normally associate with 'it just can't really be done'. A `tcbraster`-based approach would be more than welcome :-) would probably use `/tcb/raster row skip=0pt` and probably some decorator on the top/bottom line. The challenge would be to allow it to appear as if it's one environment.

Comment: @TomášKruliš I honestly didn't see the `\tcbline` portion of your answer! It would be ideal *except* it results in several errors – starting with ``You can't use `\prevdepth' in restricted horizontal mode.``

Comment: @SeanAllred Well, I have not idea what `\prevdepth` is; I am sorry ...